# Scaling Repositories horizontally on common x86 hardware

Tags: repository, scalability, jcr, fedora-commons

I was wondering if you guys had any tips which repository implementation has good clustering and horizontal scaling characteristics on common hardware?

The problem is that we have to implement a preservation system on top of a repository which is be able to ingest and manage LOTS of heterogeneous data (> 500 TB) with big files (>50GB).

[Fedora Commons](http://fedora-commons.org/) it seems can only be clustered by using a distributed filesystem. [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) can be clustered but its DataStore (for large binary data) has to be the same for all nodes in a clustered environment. Do you guys have any tips which repository systems I should check out?

Answer (score 5):

Give [ModeShape](http://modeshape.org) a try. It is a JCR 2.0 implementation that can be configured to use an [Infinispan data grid](http://infinispan.org) as its backing [store](http://docs.jboss.org/modeshape/latest/manuals/reference/html_single/reference-guide-en.html#infinispan-connector), and ModeShape is also easily clustered (it uses [JGroups](http://jgroups.org), which is the same communication library used in the clustering features in Infinispan and JBoss Application Server, among many others).